# $E$ is closed $\leftrightarrow E^{c}$ is open

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I'm having difficulty following this proof provided in Principles of Math. Analysis by Rudin.

**Pf**

First suppose $E^{c}$ is closed.  Choose $x \in E$.  Then $x \notin E^{c}$, and $x$ is not a limit point of $E^{c}$.  **Hence there exists a neighborhood** $N$ of $x$ such that $E^{c} \cap N$ is empty, that is, $N \subset E$.  Thus $x$ is an interior point of $E$, and $E$ is open.

I bolded what I do not follow exactly.  What allows us to say there exists a neighborhood $N$? Couldn't it be true that $x$ has no neighborhood in $E$?

Ie. if $x$ is not a limit point of $E$ then we have that either, there exists a neighborhood of which none of the points are in $E^{c}$, or there is no neighborhood, in which case it would be false that $x$ is interior.

Comment: It follows from the definition of a limit point. If every neighbourhood of $x$ intersected $E^c$, then $x$ would be a limit point of $E^c$.

Comment: Now just take the contrapositive of @DanielFischer's comment. If $x$ is not a limit point, there is a neighbourhood $N$ such that $N \cap E^c$ is empty.

Comment: Ok, now I think I see.  If $x$ were not a neighborhood that is a subset of $E$ then it would mean it contains a point of $E^{c}$, in which case it is a limit point of $E$.

Answer (score 0):

It follows from the following characterization of limit points:

> Let $A$ be a subset of the topological space $X$. Then $x \in \overline A$ if and only if every open set $U$ containing $x$ intersects $A$.